# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: c#, wcf, console-application

I created an eBay console app that runs from a service. If I run the console as is, it works fine. If I don't run it as it I get 'Could not find default endpoint element that references contract `'EbayFinding.FindingServicePortType'` in the `ServiceModel` client configuration section.

I've tried fully qualifying my `app.config` but that didn't seem to fix it, does anybody have any ideas?

```
 <endpoint address="https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FindingServiceSOAPBinding"
            contract="EbayFindingConsole.EbayFinding.FindingServicePortType" name="FindingServiceSOAPPort" />
    </client>
```

`contract="FindingServicePortType"` (is the original state)

Code that calls the contract:

```
using (FindingServicePortTypeClient client = new FindingServicePortTypeClient())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rest of the error message is:

> This might be because **no configuration file was found for your application**, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Since it is working when run directly, we can rule out that endpoint is missing.
The only thing that remains is that configuration file is not where it is being searched for.

Check whether the directory from which you are running the console app has the configuration file for console app.

If the console app and service executable are in same directory, that directory should contain the console app configuration file.

Comment: Maybe I am not running this the correct way and your correct.  I am cntrl + shift + B and building the app, taking that exe from the bin directory and placing it in the location I want my service to call it.  Is there a better way?

Comment: or yet, how do i figure out where it's trying to call the app.config from?

Comment: @Mike: I suppose you are not using custom configuration for you WCF client. If that is the case, the configuration file should be in same directory as the console app that service starts and its name should be `<ConsoleAppName>.exe.config` (`<ConsoleAppName>` is real name of the console app).

Comment: I heart both of you.  That was kicking my butt for 3 days,

Comment: I encountered this issue, but it was due to me using slowcheeta transform and my release configuration not being transformed properly (web reference url missing on the transformed web.config file). Just my two cents worth.